# On a differential equation with a state-dependent input

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, linear-control

Consider the following linear time-varying differential equation:
$$\label{eq:1}
\dot{x}(t)=-ax(t)+b\cos(\omega t)x(t), \quad x(0)=x_0\in\mathbb{R},\tag{$\star$}
$$
where $a$, $b$, $\omega$ are positive scalars. It is well-known from basic control theory that, if we forget about the term $x(t)$ that post-multiplies the cosine term, namely, if we consider the simplified equation
$$\label{eq:2}
\dot{x}(t)=-ax(t)+b\cos(\omega t), \quad x(0)=x_0\in\mathbb{R},\tag{$\#$}
$$
then the solution can be decoupled as a sum of a zero-input response and a forced response. More precisely, the forced response reads as
$$
x_{\text{forced}}(t)=|G(j\omega)|\cos(\omega t +\angle G(j\omega)),
$$
where $G(j\omega)=1/(1+ja\omega)$ is the frequency response of the system.

> Now my question is: Can the solution of \eqref{eq:1} be somehow related to the frequency response of the system in \eqref{eq:2}? In particular, is it possible to rewrite \eqref{eq:1} as
>   $$
> \dot{x}(t)=-ax(t)+\beta(t), \quad x(0)=x_0\in\mathbb{R},
> $$
>   where $\beta(t)\le b|G(j\omega)||x(t)|$?

I'm aware that my question is bit vague and some details are not formally stated. However, my principal aim is to gather some intuitions/ideas on a problem that I'm facing right now. So every comment/criticism/suggestion is more than welcome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: First of all, let us correct one missconception: the differential equation you pose **is** linear. It is just not time-invariant. You can write 

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=-ax+b\cos (\omega t) x=-(a-cos(\omega t))x.
$$
Now you just use variation of parameters or observe directly that an equivalent formulation is:
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x}=\int -(a-cos(\omega t))dt.
$$
I'm a bit to lazy at the moment to get into transfer function details, but I think you can probably figure out whatever properties you need from here.

Comment: To clarify, we say that an ordinary differential equation is nonlinear, if $\dot x= f(x,t)$ where $f(x,t)$ is not a linear function of $x$. As you can see above I managed to factor out the $x$, so it is actually linear. It is allowed to be nonlinear in $t$ as long as there are no $t$-derivatives showing up (in which case we have a partial differential equation but that's a story for another day).

Comment: @Winston: Correct! Thanks for the clarification, let me edit the OP.

Comment: I do not understand why my question got a downvote. This is not a homework-like question. Further on, it does not seem to me that the answer is trivial or obvious. In any case, if the MSE community actually think it is so, feel free to remove my question. But please, let me know what are the motivations.

Comment: The solution of $(*)$ is given by $$x_0 \exp\biggl(\frac{b \sin (t \omega )}{\omega }-a t\biggr).$$  According to the [Floquet theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory), it is the product of an exponential function, that is, $e^{-a t}$, and a periodic function. I don't know if that will be of much help to you.

Comment: The system is linear time-varying so, you can utilize Laplace to convert the system to s-domain then for every $s=jw$ then you can proceed from this point.